# How to write a non-equi join in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, non-equi-join

My tables include 3 date columns, dateA , dateB and dateC
What I require:

```
JOIN ON dateA between dateB and dateC
```

The JOIN works quite well in Teradata, but I'm getting errors while running in Hive.

```
select *
from
table A
left join table B
on A.col1 = B.col1
and A.dateA between B.dateB and B.dateC
```

Error:

> Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN dateB

I would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: Provide the query please. It seems columns are from different joined tables?

Comment: I have updated the description!

Comment: "Getting errors"...? Please show them

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Hive does not support non-equi joins. Move the BETWEEN join condition to the WHERE

```
select *
from
table A
left join table B on A.col1 = B.col1
WHERE (A.dateA between B.dateB and B.dateC)
      OR B.col1 is NULL --allow not joined records from A (left join)
```